# Помощь по выполнению лабораторных на Си. Работа функции isxdigit. Что значит изображение 16рич числа и как его найти

Tags: c

Это задача к лабораторной работе на заочном факультете ДонНТУ.
такая задача уже появлялась в интернете, но автору вопроса не ответили.

##Задача##:
Из исходного текста в выходной переписать все слова, которые являются изображениями шестнадцатеричных чисел.

В методичке упоминалась эта функция(макрос) isxdigit(int c)

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <ctype.h>
#include <windows.h>
#include <locale.h> //языковая база
#define RU setlocale(LC_ALL, "Russian"); SetConsoleCP(1251); SetConsoleOutputCP(1251);

void main()
{
    RU
        char* ss[90] = { "Это юольшой рассказ... в катором явно скрыт какой-то тайный смысл..." };
    ss[74] = 3С3;

    int i; 
    for (i = 0; i < 89; i++)
    {
        if (isxdigit(ss[i]))
        {
        printf("Символ [%d] = %hhx  – это 16ричная цифра\n", i, ss[i]);
        }
    }
}
```

Что значит изображение 16рич числа и как мне его найти?

Comment: `ss[74] = 3С3;` это вы написали? Что это такое? А задачу можно понять так : в тексте "i like dead beef" два последних слова можно интерпретировать как шестнадцатиричные числа

Comment: Вы сами, не компьютер, умеете найти в тексте шестнадцатеричные цифры? А шестнадцатеричные слова?